# Need help finishing loginscript with cookie

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication

My problem is, when i submit my loginform the script says "User does not exist", even though it does exist in my database.

Things working: if non of the input fields are set, it correctly print "Fill out both input fields".

PHP script

```
<? 

if(isset($_POST['login'])){////4

$hostname = "localhost";
$data_username = "xxxxx"; //database username
$data_password = "xxxxx"; //database password
$data_basename = "xxxxx"; //database name
$conn = mysql_connect("".$hostname."","".$data_username."","".$data_password."");  
mysql_select_db("".$data_basename."") or die(mysql_error()); 

$lastvisit = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");


if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])  AND isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {///3

    $check_user_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM so_users WHERE `username` = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($check_user_data) !== 0){ //// 2

        $get_user_data = mysql_fetch_array($check_user_data);
        if($get_user_data['password'] == $password){//// 1

            if (isset($_POST['rememberme'])) {
                /* Set cookie to last 1 year */
                setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], time()+60*60*24*365, '/projekter/smartorder', 'www.xxxxx.dk');
                setcookie('password', $_POST['password'], time()+60*60*24*365, '/projekter/smartorder', 'www.xxxxx.dk');
                setcookie('usertype', $get_user_data['usertype'], time()+60*60*24*365, '/projekter/smartorder', 'www.xxxxx.dk');
                mysql_query("UPDATE so_users SET visits=visits+1 WHERE username='$username'");
                mysql_query("UPDATE so_users SET lastvisit='$lastvisit' WHERE username='$username'");

            } else {

                /* Cookie expires when browser closes */
                setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], false, '/projekter/smartorder', 'www.xxxxx.dk');
                setcookie('password', $_POST['password'], false, '/projekter/smartorder', 'www.xxxxx.dk');
                setcookie('usertype', $get_user_data['usertype'], false, '/projekter/smartorder', 'www.xxxxx.dk');
                mysql_query("UPDATE so_users SET visits=visits+1 WHERE username='$username'");
                mysql_query("UPDATE so_users SET lastvisit='$lastvisit' WHERE username='$username'");
            }
            header('Location: index.php');

       }//// 1
       else { $msg = 'Incorrect password<br><div class="border"></div><br>'; }
       }/// 2
       else { $msg = 'User does not exist!<br><div class="border"></div><br>'; }
       }/// 3
       else { $msg = 'You must fill out both fields!<br><div class="border"></div><br>'; }
       }/// 4




?>
```

HTML Form:

```
<form class="boxCont" method="POST">
    <?php echo '<div class="statusmsg">'.$msg.'</div>'; ?>
        <div>
            <label for="userName">Username</label>
            <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Please enter your username here" />
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="And your password here" />
        </div>

        <div>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="login" name="login" value="Login" style="margin-top:32px;"/>&nbsp;Remember me
                    </label>​
                    <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Login" class="btn right" />
                </div>
        <div class="border"></div>
        <div style="font-size: 12px; margin-left:124px; color: #888888;">
             Arent't user yet? Register <a href="/projekter/smartorder/signup" style="color: #555555; font-weight: bold;">here</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I see that you're using the variable $username multiple times in your mySQL query but I don't see it being assigned a value anywhere in your script... perhaps this is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowhere are you setting the value of `$username` (unless you've got register_globals on, in which case... more on that later), so your query comes out as:

```
SELECT * FROM so_users WHERE `username` = ''
                                           ^--look mom, no username!
```

If you **DO** have register_globals turn on, then I suggest you immediately shut down your web server and go read the docs on the PHP site on why [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) is the greatest stupidity to ever have been put onto the public internet.

Seeing constructs like this:

```
mysql_select_db("".$data_basename."") or die(mysql_error()); 
                ^^-- huh?        ^^^-- double-huh?
```

suggest a certain amount of cargo-cult programming.

Comment: Don't even look at `$conn = mysql_connect(...`

Answer (score 2):

is there a reason you're using cookies instead of '$_SESSION'?
cookies are stored on the client's pc, where sessions are processed at the server before the server sends html to the client.

therefor it might be very unsafe to store the password in cookies instead of session variables.

> also, in your code
>
> ```
> ("SELECT * FROM so_users WHERE `username` = '$username'")
> ```
>
> lose the ` around username.

^ that is indeed unnecessary, as matthieu said, but you should keep in mind that using cookies is quite unsafe.

Comment: Many many flaws in the posted question code, i totally agree with the SESSION stuff but not with the `` they are good practice actually to put around all fields even if not a reserved keyword, because if you DO use a reserved keyword and you update mysql, then your query still stands...

Comment: I can't believe i looked over this, but yes, as all other reactions say, you never assigned $username, so the variable is empty, and basically your query asks for a row where there's an empty username.

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin you're right, however that does not apply to this code. it doesn't do much damage to keep the ``, but as i remember i ran into a problem using them once.

but that was before i read the $username var was unassigned.
that's probably the problem here.